# Remove Tomcat from XAMPP after installation

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I recently installed the XAMPP web server on Windows for use with PDT Eclipse for my web development. After installation, recreated my workspaces and re-built all the MySQL databases.

When I run the XAMPP Control I notice the error message that Tomcat is not found see below.
[image: XAMPP Control - Tomcat Issue]

As I don't use Tomcat, this is fine but it is annoying getting the red error message every time I run the XAMPP control.

I have searched everywhere that I can think of to find a way of switching Tomcat off in my XAMPP installation. The only advice I can find is to re-install XAMPP. While this is logical, I definitely do not want to have to recreate all my databases by  to get rid of this annoyance. Does anyone know of some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem with xampp recently. The solution is fortunately quite straightforward.

Look for the file xampp-control.ini in your xampp root folder (something like c://xampp/ if xampp is on your c drive). Edit this file and locate the following lines:

```
[Autostart]
Apache=0
MySQL=0
FileZilla=0
Mercury=0
Tomcat=0

[Checks]
CheckRuntimes=1
CheckDefaultPorts=1

[ModuleNames]
Apache=Apache
MySQL=MySQL
FileZilla=FileZilla
Mercury=Mercury
Tomcat=Tomcat

[EnableModules]
Apache=1
MySQL=1
FileZilla=1
Mercury=1
Tomcat=0

[EnableServices]
Apache=1
MySQL=1
FileZilla=1
Tomcat=0
```

Make sure that you set Tomcat=0 in [Autostart], [EnableModules] and [EnableServices].

This will switch the service off and you should no longer get the message that you showed in your post when you run xampp-control.exe